# Sharepoint 2013: Crawling Publishing Image Caption Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013, I am needing to return the site column "Image Caption" (static name is "Publishing Image Caption") in a query.  For some reason it does not appear to be a searched crawled property, much less a managed property.  I've even tried looking through the prefix "ows_r_HTML_" for it.  Does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property will only be created if you add the SourceID tag to your field:

**SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"**

```
<Field
   ID="{27C0BEEB-6132-420F-B953-D1C5F32E789E}"
   Name="MyField"
   StaticName ="MyField"
   DisplayName="MyField"
   SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
   Type="Image"
   RichText="TRUE"
   RichTextMode="ThemeHtml"
   Required="FALSE"
   Group="MyGroup">
</Field>
```

Make another Full Crawl afterwards and the crawled property will be added. Should be ows_r_IMGE_MyField for the example.